# I changed the admin URL path and I need to change it back, but I no longer have access to the admin panel, because I changed the admin URL. :(

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin

I changed the admin URL path and I need to change it back, but I no longer have access to the admin panel, because I changed the admin URL. :(
I forget exactly what the input form looked like, so I'm not sure exactly what I did, but as soon as I hit "save" I lost my access to the admin panel. 
How can I get into the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

If you have acces to the server the following command should help you out:

```
bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname <name>
```

You can view your current URI in:

```
app/etc/env.php
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-adminurl.html

Comment: I found that file in the code base. But, I don't see anything like the file path I used. I don't know what to change back?

Comment: In the file you should find something in the lines of: 'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin',
  ),

Comment: return array (  'backend' =>   array (    'frontName' => 'rtujrjyjuk',  ) but, i'm not seeing the URL?

Comment: Your admin URI would be: rtujrjyjuk

Comment: yes. should I change rtujrjyjuk to admin?

Comment: It's considered best practice to use the command. But you should be good if you change it in the file (just tested it myself).

Comment: It didn't work. I'm not sure what I changed. It wasn't in the code base. all I did was enter a URL into the backend user interface for the store, where I thought I was changing the "HOME" URL. when I saved the changes, I lost access to my backend admin panel.

Comment: Do you have acces to the other parts of Magento (eg. the storefront)?

Comment: yes. the storefront is still live

Comment: Try changing that env.php file and flushing your cashes trough the terminal (bin/magento c:f)

Comment: I don't have a terminal set up with access to the host environment

Comment: If you have acces to the file system. You can clear the following folders: var/page_cache - var/cache

Comment: what do you mean, "clear?"

Comment: Empty them or delete them. Those folders get recreated when you load a page again.

Comment: It keeps going to a 404 page in the storefront. :( "There was no 404 CMS page configured or found."

Comment: I feel like this isn't where I went wrong. The app/etc/env.php file seems to be directing accurately to where the admin access had been granted prior to this... whatever I did...

Answer (score 0):

I have read above conversation,
As you know to change in `app/etc/env.php` like below,

```
array (
    'frontName' => 'admin',
  )
```

After changed admin name, you must delete all directories under \pub\static directory (don't delete `.htaccess` and `deployed_version.txt` file)

And run

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command
```